# Why won't 16.04.03 with persistence boot on Dell Inspirion?

Tags: 16.04, boot, live-usb, persistence

I have two USB sticks with 16.04.03 installed on them.  One with persistence, the other not.  Both boot fine on my VAIO laptop. But the one with persistence will not boot on my Dell Inspirion. Why not?

Comment: Please tell us more about your computers, not only brand name but also model number. And describe how you created your live-only and your persistent live systems (which tools you used and what modifications you made). Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: Problem solved. Rather than try and fix the USB drive that wouldn't boot on the Dell Core 2 Duo machine, I re-installed Ubuntu persistent on the same USB from the Dell computer.  That worked. It now boots on both the Sony Vaio laptop and the Dell desktop.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) It will be even more useful for other people, if you tell us more details, for example which tool/method that you used, when you re-installed Ubuntu persistent.